# "depending {on / upon} the qualities" ... Which preposition is preferred?

Tags: prepositions

> It is difficult to predict a revolution. It could go in any direction
>   depending **on/upon** the qualities of the leader and the group. A
>   strong leader must stand by the beliefs and ideas of the revolution
>   and motivate his team for the same.

Kindly briefly explain why?

> **Kindly** briefly explain why.

Is usage of "kindly" above right?

Comment: Is this question about *depend on/upon* or *kindly*? If it's about both, I'd recommend splitting it into two questions.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, **on** and **upon** are both prepositions that can indicate time and place.

**depend on** and **depend upon** essentially mean the same. However, I would say that at least in AE (American English) **upon** is considered a bit more formal, and would be used for emphasis.

For example:

> She depends on her parents for support.
>
> She depends upon her parents for support.

Both of these mean the same thing.

> I'm really depending on you to be there for me.
>
> I'm really depending upon you to be there for me.

Again, both of these mean the same thing.